# Get second top scorer in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to MapReduce, was working on problem to find second top score for state entered
below is data

User enters CA and need to find out top second score, in this case Raphel with 900 (martin is top scorer)

[image]

Comment: This feels like a homework exercise. You need to make a reasonable attempt to work it through, and tell us what you have tried, and what is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the logical steps that I would do to arrive at the solution.

1. Read the input file where a record could have `state as key` and `score as a value`. This can be a `Map` job.
2. Post this, you need to pass it to the reduce job. IMO, since `state` is selected as a key, shuffle and sort phase should bring all the records with same state together.
3. In `Reduce` job you can implement selection of second top score by ordering the scores.